# 4D array from 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have certain number of Numpy arrays with the shape

```
print(x.shape)
>>>(256,256)
```

How can I stack them so that the shape is

```
print(y.shape)
>>>(certainnumber,256,256,1)
```

I've been trying with np.stack and np.concatenate but I only get out of axis errors or stuff like

```
print(y.shape)
>>>(anothernumber,256)
```

Comment: U need to imagine how the array looks like before coding...then you won't get such errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `axis` argument to `np.stack` to specify which axis you want to stack along:

```
arrs = [np.random.rand(256, 256) for i in range(11)]
out = np.stack(arrs, axis=0)
out.shape
# (11, 256, 256)
```

(Note that axis defaults to zero).

If you need to add a one at the end of the shape, then use a `newaxis`

```
out[..., np.newaxis].shape
(11, 256, 256, 1)
```

Comment: By default, it works along `axis=0` :) So, we can skip that axis param, but good for explanation I guess.

Comment: easiest to understand

Answer (score 3):

**Method #1**

Here's one with [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) -

```
np.stack(list_of_arrays)[...,None]
```

**Method #2**

You can prepend a new axis with `None/np.newaxis` for each of those arrays and concatenate along the first axis for `(certainnumber,256,256)` shape, like so -

```
np.concatenate([i[None] for i in list_of_arrays],axis=0)
```

Then, add new axis as the trailing one for the  final `(certainnumber,256,256,1)` shape, like so -

```
np.concatenate([i[None] for i in list_of_arrays],axis=0)[...,None]
```

**Sample runs**

```
In [32]: a = np.random.rand(3,4)

In [33]: b = np.random.rand(3,4)

In [34]: list_of_arrays = [a,b]

In [42]: np.stack(list_of_arrays)[...,None].shape
Out[42]: (2, 3, 4, 1)

In [35]: np.concatenate([i[None] for i in list_of_arrays],axis=0)[...,None].shape
Out[35]: (2, 3, 4, 1)
```

Comment: I like your answer, it gives a good window into how your mind thinks about these sorts of problems.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not sure if it shows, but my mind works better with shapes, rather than the actual values. This problem fits right into that criteria :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your arrays in some sort of container (you can always put them in a container):

```
>>> ax = [np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,3)) for _ in range(4)]
>>> ax
[array([[0, 3, 1],
       [4, 2, 4],
       [2, 2, 8]]), array([[8, 4, 6],
       [7, 1, 4],
       [8, 9, 8]]), array([[6, 3, 8],
       [4, 6, 8],
       [2, 2, 9]]), array([[1, 8, 1],
       [0, 9, 2],
       [9, 2, 3]])]
```

So, you can use `np.concatenate` but you have to reshape as well:

```
>>> final = np.concatenate([arr.reshape(1, 3,3,1) for arr in ax], axis=0)
```

with a result:

```
>>> final.shape
(4, 3, 3, 1)
>>> final
array([[[[0],
         [3],
         [1]],

        [[4],
         [2],
         [4]],

        [[2],
         [2],
         [8]]],


       [[[8],
         [4],
         [6]],

        [[7],
         [1],
         [4]],

        [[8],
         [9],
         [8]]],


       [[[6],
         [3],
         [8]],

        [[4],
         [6],
         [8]],

        [[2],
         [2],
         [9]]],


       [[[1],
         [8],
         [1]],

        [[0],
         [9],
         [2]],

        [[9],
         [2],
         [3]]]])
>>>
```

### Edit

Inspired by @Divakar to be more generic:

```
np.concatenate([arr[None,..., None] for arr in ax], axis=0)
```

Comment: A generic one (using shape params) would be nice to see.

Comment: Nice one that latest addition!

Comment: and btw how do I add another array of 256x256 to this afterwards?

Comment: It would be `out = np.append(out,ar[None,...], axis=0)` being ar another array